# How to get a object which is instantiated inside a void method?

Tags: java, variables, methods

The problem is that i got 2 classes. The first class has a method which created an object of the second class. Is it possible to get that object without having a return statement? And also not making it a field

Example:

//first class

```
public class First {

    public First() {
    }

    public void aMethod(Object o) {
        Second s = new Second(o);
    }
}
```

//second class

```
public class Second {

    public Second() {
    }
}
```

The method is called via a click of a button.

EDIT:
Sorry for the confusions. But the reason i dont want to change the code is because I'm making a JUnit test.

The two classes are actually jFrames and I'm trying to test the buttons.
In the first class the method is called via a button. In the method it creates the second Jframe. In this Jframe i also want to test a button, thats why I need the instantiated jFrame object.
In the aMethod() im also passing some paramenter, which the second JFrame needs. So I cant test It individually.

Comment: can `aMethod()` have parameter(s)?

Comment: The question you've asked doesn't really make sense - why would you not want to return `s` if you want to use it outside `First`? Please can you edit your question to explain **what** you want to achieve, not **how** you think you should achieve it?

Comment: May be this can help:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408626/returning-a-void-object

Comment: no return, no field(so static or non-static variable right?) then I guess the only way I can think of is reflection which I don't think is the right way... but I don't think that's really what you want...

Comment: @cwhsu You could do it by mutating a parameter passed into the method (basically a class which is just a wrapper for `Second`). I think this is what Kent is hinting at. However - I think the requirement makes no sense, hence why I feel the author should clarify his intent.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how thread safe your First object is/needs to be.

You could set an instance variable and then expose a getter but maybe you are trying to work inside some other constraints as this seems a pretty weird alternative to just returning the value.

```
public class First {
    private Second s;
    public First() {
    }

    public void aMethod() {
         s = new Second();
    }

   public Second getSecond(){
        return s;
   }
}
```

EDIT: Another answer, given I missed the no field constraint somehow.

You could use Observable pattern so that you client Object registers as a listener to First and then you can do;

```
Second s = new Second();
setChanged();
notifyObservers(s);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

Again this seems like overkill, maybe you could give more context as to the reason you can't edit the method signature or use fields.

Comment: `"... And also not making it a field"`

Comment: Oh yeah, not sure how I missed that Dukeling.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities I could think of:

1) add parameter in `aMethod()` for example `List list (or other types has Second Field)`, then you could `list.add(new Second())` the caller could get it from the list (last element)

2) another class (if you have), has a static field `private static Second second`, and you have to write setter/getter, also care about the thread safe problem... then you can in `aMethod()` `Foo.setSecond(new Second());` really **bad** in practice.

in the end, I would ask, do you really need do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can also return it inside a parmeter you pass into the method call.
something like:

```
    public void aMethod(Result result) {
             s = new Second();
             result.val = s;
        }
```

where Result might be a class having a member of type Second.
or maybe a generic class :

```
Result<Second>
```

But i'm not sure how that would be better than a simple return.

Answer (score 0):

The most common was is use so called Factory Pattern

```
public class First {

public First() {
}

public Second aMethod(Object o) {
    return new Second(o);
}
```

}