# Java Void type - possible/allowed values?

Tags: java, void

1) In Java, I can do this:

```
Void z = null;
```

Is there any other value except `null` I can assign to `z`?

2) Consider the following code snipped:

```
Callable<Void> v = () -> {
    System.out.println("zzz"); 
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return null;
};
```

This compiles OK, but if I remove the last statement `return null;` it doesn't. Why? After all, `Void` is supposed to mean no return value.

Comment: void and Void are two different things, the latter one is a class

Comment: I know they are different things but they are still related: "The Void class is an un-instantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uses for the Java Void Reference Type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643906/uses-for-the-java-void-reference-type)

Comment: yes but still you are defining a callable returning an instance of Void, void is not an instance of Void hence the compilation error

Comment: Point 2) logically follows from 1): if you can assign single value (`null` value), it is really single value which you can (and should) return from appropriate lambda. Nothing strange

Comment: @Andremoniy Well, I can still say `Void z;` without assigning anything to `z`. I don't think 2) follows from 1) just like that. Still, that's an interesting way of viewing this... Actually maybe you're right, it follows.

Comment: `Void z;` is obviously unitialized variable, which you will have to initialize with some (and only possible - `null`) value before usage. So this is not different case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408626/returning-a-void-object

Comment: OK, well, thanks everyone.

Comment: If you say `Void z;` as a field, then `z` will be initialized with `null`, just like 1).

Comment: Just as an FYI, `null` IS A value, it's just a special value.  Returning null and not returning anything are different things.

Answer (score 8):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html):

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

So, **no**.

`Void` is used by methods having to return an object, but really returning nothing.

A decent example can be observed with some usage of the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in Android, in cases where you don't need to return any object after the task is complete.

You would then extend `AsyncTask<[your params type], [your progress type], Void>`, and return `null` in your `onPostExecute` override.

You wouldn't need it in most cases though (for instance, `Runnable` is typically more suitable than `Callable<Void>`).

Ansering your question more specifically:

> But if I remove the return null it does not compile?! Why?

... because a `Void` is still an object. However, it can only have value `null`.

If your method declares it returns `Void`, you **need** to (explicitly) return `null`.

Comment: Thanks. Still, Runnable's run() does not throw any checked exceptions. This lambda expression from my example does. So Runnable will not work in my example.

Comment: @peter.petrov you're welcome. There are cases when using `Void` is.. ehm... unavoidable (sorry).

Comment: @peter.petrov although you can still use a `Runnable` in your example and wrap the `sleep` invocation in a `try` / `catch`.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the sources:

```
package java.lang;

public final class Void {
    public static final Class<Void> TYPE = Class.getPrimitiveClass("void");

    private Void() {
    }
}
```

*Void* is:

- final class;
- has private constructor.

Without using *Reflection* it's not possible to assign anything but **null** to a reference of *Void type*.

Answer (score 2):

> In Java, I can do this Void z = null; Is there any other value (but null) which I can assign to z ?

You can if you create you own `Void` instances.  You can use Reflection or Unsafe to create these, not that it's a good idea.

> But if I remove the return null it does not compile?! Why? After all, Void is supposed to mean just that - no return type.

Java is case sensitive, this means that `Boolean` and `boolean` are NOT the same type nor is `Void` and `void`.  `Void` is a notional wrapper for `void` but otherwise is just a class you shouldn't create any instance of.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are asking for is `Runnable` or `Consumer` - some interface that doesn't have a return value. `Void` only serves to show that you cannot expect anything else than null. It is still just a class, not a keyword or anything special. A class that cannot be instantiated, so you have to return null.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of efforts were spent in designing lambda expression to treat `int/Integer` etc indistinguishably, so that `int->Long` will be compatible with `Integer->long`, etc.

It is possible (and desirable) to treat `void/Void` in a similar way, see comments from [Goetz](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006685.html) and [Forax](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-November/006687.html).
However, they didn't have the time to implement the idea for java8 :(

You can introduce an adapter type that is both `()->void` and `()->Void`; it can simplify your use case a little bit, see http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/util/function/Callable_Void.html

---

If you have a method that accepts `()->Void`, it is not going to work well with `()->void` lambdas. One workaround is to overload the method to accept `()->void`. For example, [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

```
    submit(Callable<T> task)
    submit(Runnable task)

    ...
        submit( System::gc );   // ()->void
```

However, overloading with functional parameter types is tricky... The example above works because both accept a zero-arg function. If the function has non-zero args

```
    foo( Function<String,Void> f )   //  String->Void
    foo( Consumer<String>      f )   //  String->void
```

it's confusing to the compiler (and the programmer)

```
    foo( str->System.out.println(str) );  // which foo?
    foo( System.out::println );           // which foo?
```

Given an implicit lambda `str->expr`, the compiler needs a target type to make sense of it. The target type here is given by the method parameter type. If the method is overloaded, we need to resolve method overloading first... which typically depends on the type of the argument (the lambda)... So you can see why it is complicated.

(A zero-arg lambda is never implicit. All argument types are known, since there's no argument.)

The lambda spec does have provisions to resolve the following cases

```
    foo( str->{ System.out.println(str); } );
    foo( str->{ System.out.println(str); return null; } );
```

You may argue that in the previous example,

```
    foo( str->System.out.println(str) );
```

since `println(str)` returns `void`, the `Void` version obviously does not fit, therefore the compiler should be able to resolve it. However, remember that, to know the meaning of `println(str)`, first, the type of `str` must be resolved, i.e. method overloading of `foo` must be resolved first...

Although in this case, `str` is unambiguously `String`. Unfortunately, the lambda designer decided against to be able to resolve that, arguing it is too complicated. This is a serious flaw, and it is why we cannot overload methods like in [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
    comparing( T->U )

  //comparing( T->int )       // overloading won't work well

    comparingInt ( T->int )   // use a diff method name instead
```